# Is there a way to use AwesomiumSharp to create a System.Drawing.Image in memory?

Tags: c#, .net, xna, awesomium

Background is, I'm using XNA, and I render Awesomium to an Image, which I then make a Texture2D from.

The code to render Awesomium to an Image via a file looks something like this:

```
webView.Render().SaveToPNG("awesomium.png", true);
var image = Image.FromFile("awesomium.png", true);
```

Which works fine, but it's dog slow (as you can imagine).

Is there a way to use Awesomium to render to a System.Drawing.Image without writing out to the filesystem?

Comment: What does `webView.Render()` return?

Comment: @DarkSlipstream, it returns a RenderBuffer. The documentation for that class is here: http://www.khrona.com/docs/awesomium_v1.6_rc1/class_awesomium_1_1_render_buffer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I found my answer in [awesomiumdotnet](https://awesomiumdotnet.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/src/RenderBufferWrapper.cpp). I guess the official wrapper isn't always the most complete :/

```
public static class Rbex
{
    public static Bitmap ToBitmap(this RenderBuffer buffer)
    {
        const int depth = 4; 
        const PixelFormat pf = PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb;

        // Create bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(buffer.GetWidth(), buffer.GetHeight(), pf);

        BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0,0, buffer.GetWidth(), buffer.GetHeight()), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);

        buffer.CopyTo(data.Scan0, buffer.GetWidth() * depth, depth, false);
        bitmap.UnlockBits(data);

        return bitmap;
    }
}
```